# Construct Scala Object (Singleton) from ClassTag

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

Is it possible to do something like below? We have a `ConcreteType` which has trait definition and Object definition. At runtime I want to create Object version to access `get` method of some `ConcreteType`. Note code below throws `cannot cast to SomeTrait` exception at `asInstanceOf`. Also I am using some library that uses format below so have no choice but to work with this construct.

```
trait SomeType

trait SomeTrait[T <: SomeType] {
  def get(i: Int): Option[SomeType]
}

trait ConcreteType extends SomeType

object ConcreteType extends SomeTrait[ConcreteType]
   
def temp[T <: SomeType]()(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Option[T] = {
   asInstanceOf[SomeTrait[T]].get(1)
}
```

Comment: Why using runtime reflection for something that a typeclass would solve more easily and safely.

Comment: I ended up using TypeTag and reflection. Was wondering if there is other ways to do this.

Comment: @datauser What do you mean by "create object"? In your code snippet it's already created (`object ConcreteType`). If you write that the object extends `SomeTrait[ConcreteType]` then it must implement the method: `object ConcreteType extends SomeTrait[ConcreteType] { override def get(i: Int): Option[SomeType] = ??? }`. Why can't you write just `ConcreteType.get(1)` in your method `temp`?

Comment: @datauser `ClassCastException` is caused by calling `asInstanceOf[..]` without specifying an object   that you call `...asInstanceOf[..]` on. This means you actually call `this.asInstanceOf[..]` where `this` corresponds to the enclosing object or class  of method `temp`.

Comment: @datauser Also please add details how you're going to use method `temp`.

Comment: @datauser maybe something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/oYnKXQ7UT9qr3bVcdtxutA/2) is what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing (I asked several questions in comments), but yes, you can get the object from `ClassTag`

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime

def temp[T <: SomeType]()(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Option[/*T*/SomeType] = {
  val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror
  val classSymbol = runtimeMirror.classSymbol(tag.runtimeClass)
  val companionSymbol = classSymbol.companion.asModule
  val companionModuleMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(companionSymbol)
  val companionInstance = companionModuleMirror.instance
  companionInstance.asInstanceOf[SomeTrait[T]].get(1)
}

temp[ConcreteType]()
```